Flutter İOS Sim OptimizationProfiles/Runner.profdata
eror cod :
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           20,4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/oguzhanyuksel/Desktop/finalProject/budget_tracker/ios/OptimizationProfiles/Runner.profdata'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
missing file..........................
